# How can EFLAGS be trusted when exceptions may happen at any time, thus corrupting EFLAGS?

Tags: winapi, exception, x86

Consider this code where I am purposely causing an access violation:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    __try
    {
        *((unsigned char*)0) = 0;
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        __asm int 3;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

At the instruction of the invalid access, `EFLAGS` is `0x282` (prior to executing it). When I singlestep it changes to `0x10382`. I then single step again to pass the exception to the application. The exception handler processes the exception and returns to the normal execution flow. However, this time `EFLAGS` has been changed to `0x244`. Some of the other registers have been changed also.

If an exception may occur on potentially any instruction, how can the compiler be so certain in its usage of `EFLAGS` and the other registers when, after an exception has been handled, `EFLAGS` and possibly other registers may contain different values than prior to when the exception occurred? This is going to corrupt every branch decision thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on an incorrect premise, viz.,

> The exception handler processes the exception and returns to the normal execution flow.

You can *either* run the exception handler *or* return to the normal execution flow, but never both.  In the case of your posted code, control flow falls out of the `__except` block down to the `return` statement, it never re-enters the `__try` block.

The compiler (having no way of knowing whether the exception will be triggered) will always generate code that will work in either case.

If you want to actually see this happening in the debugger, you need some code that generates an exception that can be continued from:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char * ptr;

int filter(void)
{
    __asm int 3;  // breakpoint A
    if (VirtualAlloc(ptr, 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE) == NULL)
    {
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    }
    else
    {
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ptr = (char *)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    __try
    {
        __asm int 3;  // breakpoint B
        *ptr = 0;
        __asm int 3;  // breakpoint C
        printf("Hi\n");
    }
    __except (filter())
    {
        printf("Oops\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program will first hit breakpoint B.  You might want to take a screenshot, or make a note of the register values.

[image]

Because the memory block is reserved but not committed, attempting to write to it will cause an exception to be thrown; this calls `filter()` and hits breakpoint A.  Various flags and registers have already changed and more will change as `filter()` runs, but once the flow of control is returned back to where the exception occurred, i.e., when breakpoint C is hit, you will find that all of the original register values have been restored:

[image]

This is possible because the kernel stores the program context in which the exception occurs.

See also [`GetExceptionInformation`,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679357(v=vs.85).aspx) which allows the filter expression to determine information about the exception, including the register values that were saved at the point the exception was raised.